# Does 0.0.0.0/7 represent the same range as 1.0.0.0/8?

Tags: networking, routing, ip, cidr

The range of `0.0.0.0/7` is `0.0.0.0 - 1.255.255.255`.
The range of `1.0.0.0/8` is `1.0.0.0 - 1.255.255.255`.

[AFAIK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3655723/is-0-0-0-0-a-valid-ip-address), `0.0.0.0/8` (`0.0.0.0 - 0.255.255.255`) is not usable. So, do these represent the same range *practically*?

```
ip route add 0.0.0.0/7 dev eth1 # 1
ip route add 1.0.0.0/8 dev eth1 # 2
```

Is the effect the same?

Comment: I get it now, but I suspect you should also [read this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/189912).

Comment: @MichaelHampton +1 for the link. Edited the post.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Clearly these are not the same.

However, nothing in 0.0.0.0/8 is a valid destination address, so the *effect* of each route would be the same. Attempts to connect to anything in 0.0.0.0/8 would just fail as always with an `Invalid argument` error, while attempts to connect to 1.0.0.0/8 would be routed as specified.

Comment: Just to add to this, if you specify both routes, `1.0.0.0/8` would always be used for `1.*.*.*`, as it is more specific than `0.0.0.0/7`. Hence, `0.0.0.0/7` would be used (and fail as described) only for `0.0.0.0/8` range (`0.*.*.*` addresses).

Comment: @MatijaNalis Connections to 0.0.0.0/8 fail regardless of whether a static route is defined for them or not.